# Graphics driver update causing overheating of CPU in ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: drivers, 18.04, graphics, update-manager, overheating

I recently updated my Ubuntu 18.04.2 system using the software updater and one of the things it updated was the `mesa` library if my memory serves me right.

Now my system shows `llvmpipe (LLVM 7.0, 256 bits)` beside the `Graphics` when I see the details instead of `Intel HD Graphics`.
Now this would have been all good but it's causing my system to overheat unnecessarily.

Can anyone help me in getting my good old `Intel HD Graphics` back?

Output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591b (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 118a
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Sure can!

Comment: It is not related to `mesa`, etc.

Comment: The heating problem is because `nvidia` is not loaded, most likely because of Secure Boot.

Comment: @Pilot6 Nope, it's not caused by NVIDIA not installed, I am 1000% sure about that. And if you are not aware, `llvm 7` is provided by `mesa 18.2.2` (check https://www.mesa3d.org/systems.html) which got updated as I mentioned above.

Comment: I am 100% sure that the problem is with Nvidia. It is powered now. Disable Secure Boot and all should be OK. If you decide to argue, then go ahead... I gave you a clue. You don't have to use it and keep looking for "mesa" solutions. )))

Comment: @Pilot6 I tried all of that and so sorry to say but it did not work.